# How do you call a method against a new tab (parent tells child window to call a method)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying really hard to understand the examples I've seen, but I don't understand.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. open the current page in a new tab/window `var win = window.open('index.htm', '_blank');`
2. Call a method on the DataTable in the new window `$('#tblTarget').DataTable().page.len(100).draw();`
3. Use a listener to wait for the new tab to be ready that calls the method specified above

I don't understand how to attach my event listener to the variable that contains the new window object.  Here's what I've tried:

```
var win = window.open('index.htm', '_blank');
win.addEventListener('load', function() {
     console.log('THIS FIRES ON THE PARENT, NOT THE CHILD');
     $('#tblTarget').DataTable().page.len(100).draw();
});
win.focus();
```

I've also made attempts to add an event listener like this: 
 `$(win.document).on('load', function(){...}`, but that didn't work.

I've also tried to manipulate the DOM in the `win` object, like this: `$(win.document.body).find('#tblTarget thead').addClass('manipulate-something')`, but that didn't work either.

How do I call methods, and interact with the DOM in the new tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opener in the new window or tab

In home.html

```
function fillData(){
    return "filled on parent";
}
window.open('index2.html', '_blank');
```

on index2.html you can call fillData in this way: suppose we have an p element with id=demo.

```
$('#demo').html( this.opener.fillData( ) );
```

this will make the new tab/window call the function that is on the parent window.